# Javascript - KineticJS create own class

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, kineticjs

How to create a new class based on KineticJs Sprite class. I'm trying like this:

```
(function() {
    Kinetic.MyCircle = function(config) {
        this._initMyCircle(config);
    };

    Kinetic.MyCircle.prototype = {
        _initMyCircle: function(config) {
            Kinetic.Circle.call(this, config);
            },
        myFunc : function(){
        }
    };

  Kinetic.Global.extend(Kinetic.MyCircle, Kinetic.Circle);
})();
```

But get error: TypeError: Kinetic.Global.extend is not a function

Comment: That error should be completely clear: there's no "extend" function on `Kinetic.Global`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
Kinetic.Util.extend(Kinetic.MyCircle, Kinetic.Circle);
```

This works in KineticJS 4.5.1